# How to access the fields of an embedded class in Spring JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I have a class with 2 fields marked with @Id

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="baspas")
class BasPas
  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="bas_id", referenceColumnName="id")
  private Bas basboard;

  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "pas_id", referenceColumnName = "id")
  private pas pasboard;
 //
```

I refactored them to an Embedded class and pulled the above two @Id fields in the BasPasPK class. This will enable me to create an interface which will extend the JPARepository interface.

```
   @Embeddable
   class BasPasPK {

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name="bas_id", referenceColumnName="id")
      private Bas basboard;

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "pas_id", referenceColumnName = "id")
      private pas pasboard;
     //

   }
```

As both these fields are annotated @ManyToOne there is another end of the relationship, where in these fields are listed with "mappedBy".
for eg.

```
   @Entity 
   class Another{
    .
    .

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "basboard" cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private set<BasPas> basPas;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

But after refactoring how to access the other end of the class.

What I mean is when I am doing mvn spring-boot:run I am getting the following exception

org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

then what I did was to change the class name in

```
 @Entity
class Another{
        .
        .

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "basboard" cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Set<BasPas> basPas;
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

to this

```
 class Another{
    .
    .

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bas" cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private set<BasPasPk> basPas; //changed the classname in angle brackets to BasPasPk
    .
    .
    .
}
```

But after this I started getting this following exception.

org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class.

How to fix this, I mean how to access these properties in the other class after pulling those two property in the embedded class.

Comment: What exactly is BasPasPk set inside the Class Another ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it this way: (Assuming the name of the BasPasPK property in your entity is `id`)

```
 @Entity
class Bas{
        .
        .

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.basboard" cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Set<BasPas> basPas;
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Comment: Brilliant, must say you are brilliant, so simple a solution, I sould have guesed it. How did you make out that we can use id.fieldname, I mean can you point me towards some source for getting to know this more thoroughly.

Comment: dude are you there

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried annotating the class BasPas with @Entity ?

Comment: It's already an entity, sorry I forgot to mention that in question.